# postgresql: joining 3 tables

Tags: postgresql, join

*First post: apologies in advance if I left anything out. Please let me know and I'll update!

I’m looking for:
users who have not logged in over 30 days
where the user’s role does not equal ('owner', 'renter', 'manager')
and where the source does not equal 'internal'

I have 3 tables

1. last_login - has user login info (load_date, current_date, last_login)
2. user - has info about user being external vs internal (source)
3. role - which role user has (role_name)

I have to join 3 tables for my WHERE conditions. When I join the 3rd table , my results drop from 300 results to just 10 or so. I've checked the tables and I should get at least 200+ results.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my joins?

```
select u.id, u.username
from user as u
join last_login as ll
on u.username = ll.username
join role as r
on ll.username = r.username
where ll.loaddate = ll.current_date - 1
and ll.lastlogin < ll.current_date - 30
and u.source <> 'INTERNAL'
and r.role_name <> ('Owner', 'Renter', 'Manager')
```

Comment: I would expect this to give a syntax error. Is that your exaact syntax that works? What is the data type for role_name?

Answer (score 0):

Looking your query i suppose that you should use **NOT IN** instead of **<>**. Also try to use **INNER or LEFT JOIN**. Something like this for example:

```
select u.id, u.username
from user as u
left join last_login as ll
on u.username = ll.username
left join role as r
on ll.username = r.username
where ll.loaddate = ll.current_date - 1
and ll.lastlogin < ll.current_date - 30
and u.source NOT LIKE '%INTERNAL%'
and r.role_name NOT IN ('Owner', 'Renter', 'Manager')
```

Comment: thanks for the response~ i've done both left and inner joins and tried the not like/in and getting the same results.

Comment: 1) try to remove where conditions.
2) Run query with one single Join to find out wheres the GAP